# Why present indefinite tense has no auxiliary verb?

Tags: grammar

Every sentence contains an auxiliary. Why we don't use auxiliaries in the affirmative sentence of present indefinite tense?

Ex: I eat rice

No auxiliary.Why?

Comment: Who told you that every sentence contains an auxiliary? It's not true.

Comment: Then plz tell something about my given example.Why the sentence has no auxiliary verb?

Comment: It has no auxiliary because it's [simple present tense](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/simple-present/).

Comment: If the main verb is present tense or past tense, and there's no question or negative, then you don't need an auxiliary verb. You need auxiliaries for negation, questions, inversions, predicate nouns and adjectives, and constructions like progressive, passive, perfect, causative, inchoative, and so on. But not in the simplest cases.

Answer (score 1):

Not every sentence has an auxiliary.

The English verb can be a single word, as in

> I *eat* rice.
>
> I *like* music.
>
> I *went* to the shops.
>
> I *am* happy

In none of these examples is an auxiliary verb used.  That is because English doesn't use an auxiliary verb for the simple present or simple past tense.

To express some tenses, to form questions, to express possibility, or passive voice English uses one or more auxiliary verbs.

> I *am reading* a book.
>
> I *have seen* the Statue of Liberty.
>
> He will go, tomorrow.
>
> *Do* you *eat* rice?
>
> I *can play* piano
>
> Salt *was added* to the batter.
>
> He *could have been helped*